# Jasper report not picking up fonts when running on linux

Tags: java, fonts, jasper-reports

I am facing fonts issue with jasper ..that 'Arail' font is not available on linux OS that my application is running, To overcome  this I am using jasperreports-fonts-6.0.0.jar with Ttf files and fonts.xml and jasperreports_extension.properties with the default fonts, included this jar in my classpath ...Still some how reports while compiling not picking up these '**dejavu**' family fonts that are default specified..and same things are working on my local windows machine!...Not sure what am I missing here!! can somebody help with this issue?...Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use [Font extensions](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/functions/index.html#functions). [Creating and using font extensions](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jasper-reports/5773/font-extensions/20374/creating-and-using-font-extensions#t=201611101856253507039)

Comment: BTW a lot of those focus on copying Windows fonts to the server. This is a legal minepit. And when you use the version Microsoft released last millenium to win browser wars against Netscape (MS core fonts for the web) you're missing all the fixes and encoding  changes that happened since in the versions shipped with Windows